# Monodevelop extra g++ compiler options on linux

Tags: c++, g++, monodevelop

I am trying to port over a windows c++ application to run on linux and I am using monodevelop. I have run into a compile error, and after some research I figured out that I need to specify the -std=c++0x flag for g++ to compile it correctly. When I run g++ with this flag on the command line it compiles fine. However, I cannot see a way to add this through monodevelop. Under options->Code Generation I see some text for "extra compiler options", but there is no way to add anything to this list. No buttons or text boxes are visible. I also opened up the .cproj file to see if I could just add it manually, but I am not seeing anything obvious where I would put this. Does anyone know how to add compiler options in monodevelop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In monodevelop 4 and up, you can add custom compiler options such as -std=c++11 and so forth. To do this, you'll need the latest MonoDevelop installed, you can compile it manually from github or install it from the Ubuntu PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/v-kukol/mono-testing/ubuntu .

After you have it installed, all you have to do is go to Project > 'Project Name' Options and go to Build > Code Generation and add the compiler options where it says Extra Compiler Options.

Comment: One should right click the project name and then select options, then they will be able to go to  Build > Code Generation > Extra Compiler Options.